# Force to display overflow menu like old option menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Is it possible to force three dot overflow menu to open from bottom? Just like older option menus - I'm on Android 4.2.2 through ActionbarSherlock.

Comment: I don't know about ActionbarSherlock but the Android ActionBar has an option to split it and put the action items (and the overflow menu) at the bottom of the screen. You might want to check for something similar in ActionBarSherlock

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a default option to achieve this as far as I know but you could overwrite the standard behaviour.

Nevertheless I wouldn't recommend doing this as the soft home button could be clicked by mistake and thus your application 'closed'. 
Additionally you should orient yourself on the design guidelines and as this function is outdated you should use the new one.